# How to make item cards in a line by 3

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make an online shop. I need 3 items in a row. I tried to do it by  function but I see the cards under each other. How can I make a row of cards by 3 elements?
When I use flex the card doesn't look with the same design as now.
I think that the problem is with .product-item
Help me, please.
MY CSS:

```
    * {
   box-sizing: border-box;
   border:  1px #e2e2e2;



}
.product-item {
   width: 300px;
   height:205px;
   text-align: center;
   border:  1px #e2e2e2;
   background: white;
   font-family: "Roboto";
}

.product-item img {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   border:  1px #e2e2e2;
}
.product-list {
   background: #fafafa;
   padding: 15px 0;
}
.product-list h3 {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: "Roboto";
   text-align: left;
   margin: 25px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #333333;

}
.product-list h4 {
   font-size: 15px;
   font-family: "Roboto";
   text-align: left;
   margin: 25px;
   font-weight: 400;
   color: #666666;

}

.sell {
   font-size: 20px;
   font-family: "Roboto";
   color: #333333;
   margin: 65px;

}

.price {
   font-size: 35px;
   text-align: left;
   font-family: "Roboto";
   color: #333333;
   margin: -65px;

  
}
.cart img
   {margin-top:-60px;
   margin-left:200px;
   width:  15%;
}
```

My HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>Card set</title> <!-- Задаем заголовок документа -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cardset.css"> 
<script src="script.js"></script> 
</head>
<body>
    <div class="product-item">
  <img src="boots.png">
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Ботинки женские</h3>
    <h4>Модные ботинки из натурального нубука. Согреют Ваши ноги во время зимних морозов.</h4>
      <p><span class = 'price'>1999</span><span class = 'sell'>руб.</span><div class="cart"><img a href="" src="cart.png">

    

  </div>

</div>
    <div class="product-item">
  <img src="boots.png">
  <div class="product-list">
    <h3>Ботинки женские</h3>
    <h4>Модные ботинки из натурального нубука. Согреют Ваши ноги во время зимних морозов.</h4>
      <p><span class = 'price'>1999</span><span class = 'sell'>руб.</span><div class="cart"><img a href="" src="cart.png">
        
    

  </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this to product-item class:

```
Width:33%;
Display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of typography errors in your code (look at the `class` you are defining, look at the extra spaces, unclosed code sections in your CSS etc.)

To align three items, you can simply use `flexbox` display. Like in the example below.

```css
section {
display:flex;
}

.itemmm img {
width:100px;
height:100px;
margin:25px;
}
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <title>Card set</title>
      <!-- Задаем заголовок документа -->
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cardset.css">
      <script src="script.js"></script> 
   </head>
   <body>
   <section class="items-container">
      <div class="itemmm">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/41/chain-690088_960_720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="itemmm">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/41/chain-690088_960_720.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="itemmm">
      <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/03/26/09/41/chain-690088_960_720.jpg">
      </div>
    </section>
      
   </body>
</html>
```